# Livecycle - form1.execValidate is not a function! Then Reader crashes

Tags: livecycle, xdp-pdf

error message: form1.execValidate is not a function.   *but this has worked fine for years!*

Last week the client (large bank) rolled out a new version of Adobe Reader XI 11.0.21.    Perhaps registry keys were changed as well - don't know.

So now all livecycle forms are crashing.    Below is one error message seen on the console followed by the crash.

The code being used has been executed 10K+ times over ~5 years, over roughly 5 different forms over many versions.

```
form1.FirstPage.sfBody.sfSectionB.sfEnder.SendReferral::click - (JavaScript, client)
var res = form1.execValidate();     // does form validation, if all good returns true
if (res) {
  cLookFeel.fMailTo(event.target); 
}
```

(Code is attached to the click method on a button, cLookFeel is the name of my code block.)

And strangely - Reader then seems to (often) crash.   Go figure.

[image: Console from Reader]

followed by a crash:
[image]

Comment: Btw, the actual form did not change between working fine and then crashing - it's been stable for roughly 4 months before this with thousands of use.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out it's a known bug by Adobe on 11.0.21.   They've issued a fix.

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/release-note/acrobat-dc-august-11-2017.html